# converting http to https using self signed certificate

Tags: security, http, ssl, openssl

I want to convert my http request to https using my self signed certificate.
How to create my keystore files and add certificate in keystore,how to use this keystore file for converting http to https.

Please sort out this problem

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but adding this code to htaccess will redirect all http to https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use KEYTOOL to generate a keypair along with Keystore below command will give you keystore which will have the private / public keypair

```
keytool -genkeypair -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias tempAlias -keystore /temp.keystore -ext SAN=dns:abc.com,dns:localhost,ip:xx.xx.xx.xx
```

to generate Self Signed Certificate use below command

```
keytool -export -alias tempAlias -keystore /temp.keystore -file /temp.crt
```

To import a certificate into your trsutstore

```
keytool -import -alias tempAlias -file PATH_TO_CRT_FILE -keystore PATH_TO_TRUSTSTORE
```

Depending on the server you can configure the server to make the request HTTPS for example in tomcat you need to update the connector tag in server.xml to something like below

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
    clientAuth="false" 
    keystoreFile=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE 
    keystorePass=KEYSTORE_PASSWORD maxThreads="150" 
    port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" 
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    truststoreFile=PATH_TO_TRUSTKEYSTORE
    truststorePass=TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD/>
```